# WPF menus with shortcuts and custom RoutedCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, shortcut, routedcommand

Im new to WPF so i might be missing something. I have a simple function in my MainWindow class called StartService. I wanted to add a menu item "Start Service" with a shortcut Ctrl+S to my application. I had to do the following:

1. In my MainWindow class i had to define:

   `public static RoutedCommand StartServiceRoutedCmd = new RoutedCommand();`
2. In my XAML code i added:

```
<MenuItem Header="_Start Service" InputGestureText="Ctrl+S" Click="OnStartService" />

<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static loc:MainWindow.StartServiceRoutedCmd}" 
                    Executed="OnStartService" />
</Window.CommandBindings>

<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="loc:MainWindow.StartServiceRoutedCmd" Gesture="CTRL+S" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Things are working. I'm wondering if this is the correct and organized way to go? I am gonna need a shortcut for my StopService function. Does this mean i will need to define a new RoutedCommand StopServiceRoutedCmd, and so on for every shortcut i need?

Comment: Yes you would need a new RoutedCommand for stopping the service. Everything else looks fine.

Comment: I actually realized that my menu item entry should also look like this:  <MenuItem Header="_Start Service" InputGestureText="Ctrl+S" Command="loc:MainWindow.StartServiceRoutedCmd" />

That way i get validation everywhere if i ever add a CanStartService().

I'm glad to know im on the right track. :)

Comment: I think you were using the event based method before and while transforming to commands you forgot to change that:) Yes! you need to use a command there. Sometimes you may have trouble changing from events to commands. For that, you can use the MVVM Light Toolkit's EventToCommand Behaviour which will be more useful. http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<MenuItem Header="_Start Service" InputGestureText="Ctrl+S" Command="loc:MainWindow.StartServiceRoutedCmd />

<Window.CommandBindings>
       <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static loc:MainWindow.StartServiceRoutedCmd}" 
                Executed="OnStartService" />
       </Window.CommandBindings>

<Window.InputBindings>
       <KeyBinding Command="loc:MainWindow.StartServiceRoutedCmd" Gesture="CTRL+S" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```